# Is there a seamless way to switch between video and screenshare for recording a presentation?

Tags: hangouts-on-air

Basically, showing a PowerPoint slide, then moving to video to talk about it, then switching back to the slide, and so on. Right now it looks like I would have to turn slide sharing on and off each time I wanted to switch between the two modes. Ideally we'd want to be able to avoid this.

Also, is there a way to have the speaker thumbnail display over the screenshare?

It shows up in the browser but appears to be missing in the final video.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I have for a macbook is to use Photobooth as a fullscreen app and screenshare on one fullscreen space. So your presentation would be displaying the whole time and your photobooth would be running the whole time. When you want to discuss something on camera, go to the Photobooth desktop, when you want to show the powerpoint, go to the appropriate space.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, this would not be a Macbook situation but it is a clever idea. My only concern for this technique is that I think you can only have the camera going in one app at a time. So if you had Google Hangouts open you couldn't also get video on Photobooth. But that might no longer be the case.

Comment: True, that's why you should turn off the video inside google hangouts.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a way to do this. I was wanting to do the same thing with regard to the not needing to switch the screensharing on an off all the time to swap between slides and seeing video.

If you invite yourself to the hangout on a different email address, turning off audio and video for one, and then on the muted no video feed, turn on screensharing for just the window that has slides. Then, you can just click on that "person" in the hangout whenever you want to show the slides, and then unclick it to have whoever is speaking's video to be shown, or select the person whose video should be shown. I just tested it out and it totally worked.

There's a couple of things you have to do. Use a different Chrome profile to open the second hangout, for me I just invited my husband and used his Chrome profile on my computer. Then, you also need to mute the tab in Chrome for the screenshare hangout. Otherwise you'll get horrible feedback in your audio. To do that, just right-click on the tab and choose "Mute tab" from the options listed.